# if-condition on array of booleans in Modelica

Tags: modelica

I'm sorry if this is a 'read the manual' question (I did but can't find an answer).

I have an array of Booleans and I want to test if any of them is true.

```
model TestArray

(...)
Boolean[:] booleanArray;
Real y;

equation
y = if [if any element in booleanArray is true] then ... else ...;

end TestArray;
```

How can I do this?
Thanks,
Roel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are functions like the ones you are requesting in Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.

Here you'll find allTrue(Boolean b[:]), anyTrue(Boolean b[:]) and oneTrue(Boolean b[:]).

Comment: Wonderful, I guess that's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question.  Frankly, I'm not aware of any built-in capabilities for doing this (although the need for such capabilities is certainly valid).

What we've frequently done in the past is to write utility functions called "any" and "all", that look like this (untested, but you get the idea):

```
function any
  input Boolean vals[:];
  output Boolean result;
algorithm
  result := max({if i==true then 1 else 0 for i in vals})==1;
end any;

function all
  input Boolean vals[:];
  output Boolean result;
algorithm
  result := min({if i==true then 1 else 0 for i in vals})==1;
end all;
```

This is similar to what you did but using array comprehensions and then encapsulating that in functions.  This allows you to write code like:

```
if any(conditions) then ... else ...;
```

Ideally, these functions could be added to the built-in set of "reduction operators" (like min and max), but the language group tends to be somewhat conservative about introducing such operators because they pollute the namespace and create potential collisions with existing code.

Note that things get a bit tricky when using when clauses.  With when clauses, there is a vector construction, e.g.

```
when {cond1, cond2, cond3} then
  ...
end when;
```

Which has very useful semantics, but is not 100% analogous to either "any" or "all" as written above.  So if you intend to use a vector of conditions in a when clause, then read up on how this is handled (in the specification) or ask a follow-up question on that and I can elaborate more (it is somewhat beyond the scope of this question).

Comment: Thanks Michael, that looks like a good solution!  At the moment, I'm not using this vector in a when clause, so the day I need it and I don't understand the specifications, I'll get back to you.

Comment: Did the specification of `min` and `max` change over time? (See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71503769/2708138) below.)

Answer (score 2):

[Section 10.3.4 of Modelica Specification Version 4.3](https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf#page=125) allows Boolean arrays `v` as arguments of `min(v)` and `max(v)`.

If all components of `v` are `true` then `min(v)` gives `true`, `false` otherwise.
If all components of `v` are `false` then `max(v)` gives `false`, `true` otherwise.

Example model:

```
model Test
    Boolean anyFalseGivesFalse = min( { true, false } );
    Boolean allTrueGivesTrue = min( { true, true } );
    Boolean allFalseGivesFalse = max( { false, false } );
    Boolean anyTrueGivesTrue = max( { false, true } );
end Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I found a workaround, but it must be possible to do it much nicer:

```
model TestArray

(...)
Boolean[:] booleanArray;
Real y;
Real[:] test;

equation
for i in 1:size(booleanArray):
  test[i] = if booleanArray[i] then 1 else 0;
end for;

y = if sum(test) > 0 then ... else ...;

end TestArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Modelica.Blocks.Math.BooleanToInteger to convert your Boolean-array to an Integer-array with which you can calculate ...

Comment: Unfortunately, Modelica.Blocks.Math.BooleanToInteger is not a function, but an object that has to be instantiated in order to use it.  That makes this solution less useful I fear.